# Linq to entities- How to translate to LIKE operator from multiple search terms

Tags: sql, linq-to-entities

I'm using Linq to Entities to filter all course names (from Sql Server database) that contains e.g. Math.

With just one term, it's very easy. I just need have the following code.

```
filteredCourses = from f in filteredCourses
                      where f.Name.Contains("math") 
                      select f;
```

This is translated in SQL to: WHERE name LIKE '%math%'. And it is just fine!

But if i have a list of terms, for example:

```
var query = new string[] { "math", "drawing" };
```

I tried this code

```
filteredCourses = from f in filteredCourses
 where query.Contains(f.Name)
 select f;
```

but it translates to WHERE name IN ('math', 'drawing')

How can i do so it is translated in SQL to:

```
WHERE name LIKE '%math%' OR name LIKE '%drawing%'
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can do like this: `filteredCourses = from f in filteredCourses
 where query.Any(q=>q.Contains(f.Name))
 select f;` But it will give you a very ugly sql query

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution only works when search term is exactly the same as course name. Thks

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant this:  `filteredCourses = from f in filteredCourses 
                  where query.Any(q=>f.Name.Contains(q)) select f;` It stills creates a very long SQL query, that's why I'm not posting it as a solution, you might need to create a stored procedure

Comment: This one works. Thank You very much.
I'll try to optimize it later but for now, it is great

Comment: May I post it as an answer, would you mark it?

Comment: yes. It definitely is a valid answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework, you can do like this:

```
filteredCourses = from f in filteredCourses 
              where query.Any(q=>f.Name.Contains(q)) select f;
```

It will produce a SQL query close to this:

```
"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[filteredCourses ] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT   1 AS [C1]   FROM  
(SELECT     N'SEARCH_QUERY_1' AS [C1]          
FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]     
UNION ALL            
SELECT N'SEARCH_QUERY_2' AS [C1] FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable2]) AS [UnionAll1]           
WHERE ( CAST(CHARINDEX([UnionAll1].[C1], [Extent1].[Name]) AS int)) > 0)"
```

If you're using Linq to SQL, this will not work.

Depending on the amount of data you have that might not be efficient, and it might be better for you to create a **stored procedure** using wildcards.